# How do I get "posts" to show up in the admin sidebar in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am removing all items that I do not want on the sidebar and I thought it would be easier to tell wordpress what I want to show up instead of what I dont want to show up so that if things get added in the future they wont show up on the side bar by default.

I have added this code and everything is showing up like it should except for posts and the logout link that I have at the bottom. Can anyone help me figure this out? I know I am using the correct slug so Im not sure why its not working.

```
add_action('admin_init', 'nwcm_admin_init');

 function nwcm_admin_init()
 {   
      if (!current_user_can('editor')) {
      return;
  }
  $menus_to_stay = array(
    'index.php',
     'edit.php',
    'upload.php',
    'edit.php?post_type=page',
   'nav-menus.php',
    'post-new.php',
    'admin.php?page=logout'
       );      
     foreach ($GLOBALS['menu'] as $key => $value) {          
    if (!in_array($value[2], $menus_to_stay)) 
    remove_menu_page($value[2]);
    }   

     }
```

I need to do this in functions.php and not with a plugin so please dont recommend plugins!

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding plugins :) See [Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72160/12615) and also [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action is not correct, use `admin_menu`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'nwcm_admin_init');
function nwcm_admin_init()
{
    if (!current_user_can('editor'))
        return;

    $menus_to_stay = array(
        'index.php',
        'edit.php',
        'upload.php',
        'edit.php?post_type=page',
        'nav-menus.php',
        'post-new.php',
        'admin.php?page=logout'
    );
    foreach ($GLOBALS['menu'] as $key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($value[2], $menus_to_stay))
            remove_menu_page($value[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Holy crap. I hate when its the simplest of things that you just overlook. Thank you!